# Information about Random Trees

Tags: probability-theory, trees, random-graphs

I want to know about Random Trees, I mean, the "first" information about them, and the people who is working and is a reference on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "random trees mathematics", check the first link from the French math school ENS Ulm, read the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511515.pdf . If too advanced (these guys are in the top math league), check its bibliography - several books are in the first lines.

**Hope this helps!**